# How do I add an extension to a file when downloading it?

Tags: ruby, open-uri

This magical Ruby script downloads a couple of XML files from a website, but the files don't have an extension. I'd like to add the prefix `.xml` to every file it downloads.

This is where I am right now and it won't work:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

URL = 'localhost'
extension = '.xml'

Nokogiri::HTML(open(URL)).xpath("//a/@href").each do |src|
  src = File.join(extension).last
  File.open(File.basename(src),'wb') do |f| 
    f.write(open(src).read)
  end
  puts "Done with: #{URL}"
end
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: I assume you meant *extension*, not *prefix*, and I've updated your question to reflect that.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, yeah thanks mate. A prefix is a word part added to the beginning.

Comment: As a warning to anyone using the above code; As written, it has potential to retrieve the same URL multiple times, wasting time and bandwidth. It's common for a page to have multiple links to other pages on a site, and each will be visited as the code loops over the `<a>` tags. Because the OPs requirement is for XML files listed in a page it's likely to avoid that problem, but other uses of the code will probably not be so lucky. Add a `set` that tracks the previously retrieved URLs, or scan the page first for URLs and store them in the set, and then iterate over it.

Comment: @theTinMan yeah, the code is a bit lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the `href` attributes in your page's links contain absolute paths. With that in mind, this *should* work.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

base_url = 'localhost'
extension = '.xml'

Nokogiri::HTML(open(base_url)).xpath("//a/@href").each do |src|
  File.open(File.basename(src.value, File.extname(src.value)) + extension,'wb'){ |f| 
    f.write(open(src.value).read)
  }
  puts "Done with: #{URL}"
end
```

Comment: I'd recommend coding a bit more defensively: `file_name = File.basename(src.value, File.extname(src.value)) + extension` will protect against a filename with an extension, whatever it is, while still adding the desired `'.xml'`. Without that you could end up with doubled filename extensions, such as `'.xml.xml'`.

Comment: Agreed, and besides, I realized that this script would not work given the problem posed in the question. I'll be coming back with an edit in a short while.

Comment: Done. This should download the file using its original file name, and save it with an `.XML` extension.

Comment: Nice stuff @loannis Karadimas.. But I get the following syntax error:

Comment: A rogue paren(`)`) was the culprit. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `File.join()` is wrong. `.join()` returns a string, and then applying `.last` to it generates an error, because there is no `.last` method for String objects.

```
pry(main)> extension = '.xml'
=> ".xml"
pry(main)> File.join(extension).last
NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for ".xml":String
```

Instead you need to pass an array of path elements you want to join into a path to a file:

```
pry(main)> File.join('.', 'path', 'to', 'a', 'file.ext')
=> "./path/to/a/file.ext"
```

or:

```
pry(main)> File.join('/', 'path', 'to', 'a', 'file.ext')
=> "/path/to/a/file.ext"
```

Take the time to read about Ruby's [`File`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html) class. It allows you to work with the files and paths in a fairly OS-independent way.

Its `dirname`, `basename`, and `extname` methods are convenient when dissecting paths:

```
pry(main)> File.dirname('/path/to/a/file.ext')
=> "/path/to/a"
pry(main)> File.basename('/path/to/a/file.ext')
=> "file.ext"
pry(main)> File.extname('/path/to/a/file.ext')
=> ".ext"
```

There's also the `split` method which combines `dirname` and `basename`, returning both the path and "filename.ext" allowing you to use parallel assignment:

```
pry(main)> dirname, filename = File.split('/path/to/a/file.ext')
=> ["/path/to/a", "file.ext"]
```

`File.basename` takes an optional "extension" parameter, allowing it to strip off an extension:

```
pry(main)> File.basename('/path/to/a/file.ext', '.ext')
=> "file"
```

Combine all that magical goodness and you can fold, spindle and mutilate your filenames and paths all day long.